# Delete strings matching multiple patterns from a list

Tags: text-processing

I have a file with lines :

```
1
apple
2
orange
3
banana
4
mango
5
coconut
```

I have a list of patterns :

```
1
3
5
```

I want to delete the lines (and one additional line after) using the list of patterns, in order to get :

```
2
orange
4
mango
```

Since I have a large number of patterns that I could not type manually one by one in a single command, a list must be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***sed*** + ***paste*** solution:

```
sed -E "/\<(`paste -s -d'|' patterns`)\>/{N;d;}" file
```

The output:

```
2
orange
4
mango
```

---

- `paste -s -d'|' patterns` - merge lines of file `patterns` using `|` as a dilimiter to get the regex alternation group `(1|3|5)`
- `N` - append the next line to the pattern space
- `d` - delete lines of pattern space

Comment: This works for the given example, but would remove `10` `lemon` as well.

Comment: @Philippos, ok, see my update

Comment: Should work now, at least for `sed` versions supporting `\< \>`.

Comment: @JohnnyTam, you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

Let's do some `grep` option juggling:

You could `grep` for all lines in your fruit file except for those in your list file with numbers to be excluded:

```
grep -v -x -f numbers fruits
```

(`-f` to give a pattern file, `-x` to prevent partly matches and `-v` to invert the match)

Unfortunally, the numbers and the fruits are on separate lines, so the fruits survive the grep. Let's get rid of them with an additional `-e` pattern:

```
grep -v -x -e "[a-z]*" -f numbers fruits
```

Now all lines consisting of letters only are removed, so no fruits anymore, not even the wanted ones. But we can recover them from the context:

```
grep -v -x -A1 -e "[a-z]*" -f numbers fruits
```

(`-A1` gives an additional line after every match) finally gives what you wanted.

Comment: I tried RomanPerekhrest's solution and it worked already. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this .

The `pattern_file` has all your `patterns` and the rest content in `file_content`. Here I tried `grep` with option `-A 1` which can change depending on number of lines after patter match.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read pattern 
do
        for line_num in `grep $pattern file_content -A 1 -n | awk -F":|-" '{print $1}' | paste -sd ","`
        do
                sed -i "${line_num}d" file_content
        done
done < pattern_file
```

Comment: I tried RomanPerekhrest's solution and it worked already. Thank you so much!